# Spring-boot security remember-me token not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

For some reason I cannot get Spring-Security to work with remember-me.
It never creates the cookie on the client side.

Here is my login form

`<input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me"/> Remember me`

also tried

`<input type="checkbox" name="remember-me"/> Remember me`

Here is my SecuritySettings

```
        http.authorizeRequests()
        ......
        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error").permitAll()
        .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds(31536000);
```

I tried both my own custom form, and the built in Spring login form.. none work for remember me.

The way I tested is, login, copy secured url, close browser, open browser and paste url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is as simple as changing fullyAuthenticated() to authenticated().

As in javadocs for fullyAuthenticated() it is said :

> Specify that URLs are allowed by users who have authenticated and were not "remembered".